# How to access values in UIViewController class from TableCell class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, I have a `UIViewController(PledgeViewController)` with a `TableView`. When the user clicks on a `UIButton(plusBtn)` in the `UITableViewCell(PledgeTableViewCell)` of the `TableView`, I want to perform a write to my firebase database. But to get the exact path, I need a String(getID) from the `PledgeViewController` class which is received with a segue from the previous ViewController. With the MVC format that I'm using, how do I access values in the `PledgeViewController` to write to the database from the `PledgeTableViewCell`?

[image]
My PledgeViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase
import Firebase

class PledgeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{


    var getID: String!

    @IBOutlet weak var pledgeAmtLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var RewardChooseTable: UITableView!
    @IBAction func pledgeBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        //get the text from the label and run all the checks to see if the tickets are available

    }

    let RewardRef = Database.database().reference().child("Rewards")

    var rewards = [Rewards]()

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rewards.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TakePledgeCell", for: indexPath) as! PledgeTableViewCell
        let reward = rewards[indexPath.row]
        cell.reward = reward
        return cell

    }



    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        RewardRef.child(getID).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            self.rewards.removeAll()

            for child in snapshot.children {
                let childSnapshot = child as! DataSnapshot
                let reward = Rewards(snapshot: childSnapshot)
                self.rewards.insert(reward, at: 0)
            }

            self.RewardChooseTable.reloadData()
        })

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("The id received from the SingleViewControl is:" + getID)
}

}
```

My PledgeTableViewCell.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class PledgeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var rewardAmtLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ticketClasslabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ticketDescLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var ticketCountLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var plusBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var minusBtn: UIButton!
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var artcallid: Int!

    @IBAction func minusBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    }


    var reward: Rewards! {
        didSet {

            rewardAmtLabel.text = "Rs. " + String(reward.rewardAmt)
            ticketClasslabel.text = reward.reward_class_name
            ticketDescLabel.text = reward.reward_desc
            print(reward.reward_class_name + " is one of the rewards")

        }

    }

    @IBAction func plusBtn(_ sender: AnyObject) {


    }


}
```

Rewards.swift:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class Rewards {
    let ref: DatabaseReference!
  //  let countRef: DatabaseReference!
    var rewardAmt: Int!
    var rewardsLeft: Int!
    var reward_class_name: String = ""
    var reward_amt: String = ""
    var reward_desc: String = ""
    var rewardID: String = ""
    var tickUpCount = 0
    var tickDownCount = 0

    init(text: String) {
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Fund").childByAutoId()
      //  countRef = Database.database().reference().child("Testing").childByAutoId()
    }



   init(snapshot: DataSnapshot)
    {
        ref = snapshot.ref
        if let value = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
            rewardAmt = value["reward_ticket_amount"] as! Int
            reward_class_name = value["reward_ticket_amount_class_name"] as! String
            reward_amt = value["reward_ticket_amount_txt"] as! String
            reward_desc = value["reward_ticket_class_desc"] as! String
            rewardsLeft = value["rewards_left"] as! Int
            rewardID = snapshot.key

        }
    }

    }

extension Rewards{

    func countUp(){
        tickUpCount += 1
        ref.child("uppingTicket").setValue(tickUpCount)

    }

}
```

Comment: You can also create one delegate method to viewController which call when button click and on button action you can pass self.reward object in that delegate and perform further code in viewCotroller. and in VC you already value in getID variable.

Comment: Can you please explain further?

Comment: Please search how to call custom delegate method. it will give you more idea about this, and answer given by sh_khan you can also implement like that for short way solution.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add a new var

```
class PledgeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var currentID = ""
}
```

and set it in `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.currentID = getID
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with closure

```
class PledgeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  //Define a closure

    var closure:(() -> Void)? = nil

@IBAction func plusBtn(_ sender: AnyObject) {

 // Do you stuff

   closure?()
    }
}

    class PledgeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TakePledgeCell", for: indexPath) as! PledgeTableViewCell

            let reward = rewards[indexPath.row]
            cell.reward = reward
            cell.closure = {
        // You will get the callback in this block
       // You can define the parameterized closure to return the value

    }
            return cell
 }
```

Comment: If I wanted to get the indexRow of that row which was selected, how would I go about it using this method?

Comment: My question is how would I get the indexRow of the row selected to the PledgeTableViewCell.swift class from the PledgeViewController. swift

Comment: At the callback time you are in the current selected index path and you can get like ths  -  let indexpathRow = indexPath.row

Comment: Can you please update it in the actual answer so that I can upvote it?

Comment: Another way - you can add the cell's button target inside the cellForRowAtIndex and in the selector find the index path through the superView -     @objc func selectorMethod(sender: Any){
        guard let cell = (sender as AnyObject).superview??.superview as? YourTableCell else {
            return // or fatalError() or whatever
        }
        
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    }

Comment: I'm getting an error saying 'Invalid redeclaration of 'PledgeViewController'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176335/discussion-between-ashish-rai-and-arjun-ram).